# Converting cURL request to http.Request

Tags: http, go, curl

This cURL command works how it should:

```
curl -i -v  http://localhost:81/hallo
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 81 (#0)
> GET /hallo HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:81
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
1 -1 0* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Now I tried to do the same http-request in my go-service like this:

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:81/" + url.QueryEscape("Hallo"), nil)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
```

If I run the go code (I tried it with a test) it only produces this error: `I only get the error net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP status code "-1"`.
(I initially tried  `http.Get(myurl)`. this produces the same http Request. the current code was generated by https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/ )

Can anyone help me to understand why this two request produce different results?

Comment: Your Go code produces a request for `GET http://localhost:81/Hallo`, while your curl request is for `GET http://localhost:81/hallo`. Is it possible the server is treating the path as case-sensitive?

Comment: thanks @Abhijit_K , I added the Command to the output of the command.

Comment: @Adrian thank you Adrian. No the server is not Case Sensitve. I try to use SentiStrength ( http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/#Java ). It is started as java server and if localhost:81/<anytext> is called it prints anytext in the log (which is happening in any way of requesting the data, even if I copy the request-url to my browser). So the server gets the request and answerrs it.  But only the cURL command prints out the response.

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that `"http://localhost:81/" + url.QueryEscape("Hallo")` is wrong. If you're going to construct the path of a URL this way, you should use `url.PathEscape`.  `url.QueryEscape` is for query paramters.

Comment: Hey @Flimzy thanks for your tip. I will change it to url.PathEscape().

Answer (score 2):

Sample request and response to a really server:

```
[@xxxx ~]# curl -v -i 10.103.118.178:40000/ready
* About to connect() to 10.103.118.178 port 40000 (#0)
*   Trying 10.103.118.178...
* Connected to 10.103.118.178 (10.103.118.178) port 40000 (#0)
> GET /ready HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 10.103.118.178:40000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Fri, 25 Dec 2020 01:43:05 GMT
date: Fri, 25 Dec 2020 01:43:05 GMT
< content-length: 2
content-length: 2
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

<
* Connection #0 to host 10.103.118.178 left intact
ok
```

You use `-i` to tell curl to include headers in the output. However, I cannot see any valid HTTP response header in your curl output. So probably your server is malfunctioning and did not make a valid HTTP response. So the Go program correctly reports about this, that it cannot interpret it as a valid HTTP header. (It tried to interpret it as an HTTP response header, but in where a status code should appear, it found `-1` which is not a valid HTTP response code)

Comment: Hey @fefe. I think you are right, the server does not return valid headers. But I can't change the Server and need to work with it like it is. Do you know any way to parse the response in my go code without valid HTTP Headers

Comment: It seems that your server may be not an HTTP server, so you cannot use an HTTP client with it. So first you should make sure what protocol the server is using, and then find a client for that protocol. If there is no client for that, then you'll have to implement your own client.